# Create the triangles in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

How this one can achieved in CSS. I googled out but i didn't find any solution.

Comment: Check to this   http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Checkout http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-breadcrumb-navigation or http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/  This is will be good help for future

Comment: I've just made a demo for you here http://jsfiddle.net/8t2E8/6/

Comment: -1: what have you tried? How far did you manage to go? What precise problems do you have: no idea where to start; can do all but not the white arrows; etc?

Comment: Sry for the late for me the actual problem is white arrows i got the solution.. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @KingKing your code is mostly effective but last one is having also an arrow.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but i will recommend @KingKing demo

Comment: @RIADev it's easy to achieve exactly what you want http://jsfiddle.net/8t2E8/7/

Comment: Yes buddy your answer is correct...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

### HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1. Account Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2. Verification</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3. Enjoy</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### StyleSheet

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 .2em 0 1em;
}
.nav ul a {
    background: red;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.nav ul li:first-child a:before {
    content: normal;
}
.nav ul li:last-child a:after {
    content: normal;
}
.nav ul a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    left: -1em;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
.nav ul a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    border-top: 1.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 1em solid red;
    right: -1em;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ts39X/1/)</kbd>**

Comment: only FireFox and IE render the arrow tabs OK, **but** Chrome, Opera (maybe all the webkit-based browsers) and Maxthon render the arrows ugly. Just try the fiddle in Chrome and you'll understand that this is not the best solution. It need more tweaks to render the arrows fine in Chrome, Opera ...

Comment: @KingKing If you should have posted your try as answer then it is only acceptable...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <p>1. Acount Info</p>
</div>

<div class="arrow2">
    <p>2. Verification</p>
</div>

<div class="arrow3">
    <p>3. Enjoy</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    width: 200px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.arrow:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 201px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid red;
}

.arrow2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
margin-left: 8px;
}
.arrow2:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 201px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid red;
}


.arrow2:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid white;
}

.arrow3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
margin-left: 8px;
}
.arrow3:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid white;
}

p {
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

And the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nryN/4/)**

Comment: Really i will appreciate your answer. It will be helpful for responsive designs

Answer (score 2):

> Here's my attempt: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xDeCd/

This example works well even if the user changes his font-size or triggers a page zoom. List-items should not break in several lines if the browser is resized.

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Markup**

```
<ol>
  <li>1. Account info</li>
  <li>2. Verification</li>
  <li>3. Enjoy</li>
</ol>
```

(add links if/where necessary, I've just supposed they are not links but simply information labels about the required steps during a process).

**Relevant CSS**

```
ol {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li:after, li:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 100%; 
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin-right: 3em;
  background: #d12420;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font: 1em/3em Arial;
}

li + li { margin-left: -1.8em; }


li:not(:last-child):after {
  left: 100%;  
  content: "";

  border-left: 1em  solid #d12420;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent; 
}

li + li:before {
  content: "";
  right: 100%;

  border-left: 1em  solid #transparent;
  border-top: 1.5em solid #d12420;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid #d12420;  
}


li:nth-child(1) { z-index: 3; }
li:nth-child(2) { z-index: 2; }
li:nth-child(3) { z-index: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, it may be useful for you
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dDG7J/)
        `<div class="breadcrumb flat">
    <a class="active" href="#">1.Account Verification</a>
    <a href="#">2.Verification</a>
    <a href="#">3.Enjoy</a>
 </div>`

Comment: why down voted this answer?? just check the DEMO link

Comment: I didn't downvoted but if I have to guess the reason of downvote, it could be related to the choice of the markup and/or the page background that is not visible under the items in the demo