# Using full-width triangle background with zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using ZURB Foundation 5 on a project. I want to code a design similar like [this !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnshl.jpg). Header and Content are clear but I don't know how to code the h1-tag title with the blue triangle background. The background starts on the very left side of the browser and should end after 9 of the 12 columns like displayed in the image. This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="title">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut diam nulla</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#title {
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:250px;
}

#title h1 {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    height:250px;
}

#title:before, #title:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#title:before {
    background: green;
    left: 0;
    width:60%;      
}

#title:after {
    background: grey;
    right: 0;
    width:40%;
    border-top: 250px solid white;
    border-left: 105px solid green;    
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zttr/hgp3grsz/

**How can I set up that the triangle ends exaclty after 9 of 12 columns?**

Comment: you can create that with simple css. use `overflow` `border` and of course `background-color`

Comment: create a fiddle so we can play at ease

Comment: there are a couple of questions on stackoverflow already, which may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383180/creating-triangles-in-css  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008898/create-the-triangles-in-css

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zttr/hgp3grsz/2/